# Safari Version 14.0.2 on big sur problem selecting text in PDF

Tags: safari, big-sur

I'm having some weirdness while trying to quote materials from a text PDF document. I recently updated to big sur and it may have something to do with that.

Can someone go to this PDF: https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Oral_History/Motorola_68000/102658164.05.01.acc.pdf

and try selecting text on any page after page 2? I can select fine on the first two pages, but not after that. I'm trying to figure out if this is a problem in Safari or the PDF itself.

Comment: No issues at all Safari 14.0.2 on Mojave. try opening it in Preview & see what happens.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yup, works in preview. Looks like a safari bug.